# Volley send parameters and JSON body

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send some data to the server and the data has some parameters and it has a large body of JSON. I  am trying to use a`Volley` to send this data.
The `getParams()` function is never called for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
final StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Sent Data");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.config_changed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Data Not Sent Because server could not verify");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.msg_data_not_sent, error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}) {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> pars = new HashMap<>();
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getParams: Called");
        }
        pars.put(PARAM1, "testf18");
        pars.put(PARAM2, "Save");
        return pars;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getBody: Called");
            }
            return response.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", response.toString(), "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }
};

RequestHelperClass.addToRequestQueue(stringReq, getContext());
```

Please help.

Comment: have you checked the request using postman?

Comment: The request access a servlet that runs on Google App Engine and I can see the request there and it says both Param1 and Param2 are nul

Comment: check if the keys - `PARAM1, PARAM1` are correct and matches with that expected by your backend, if that didn't work share your api url

Comment: Yeah they are correct. The `getParams()` function is not getting called

Comment: share your api url, param keys

Comment: I fixed the problem by using `HttpUrlConnection` instead of Volley